# error en formularios dinámicos en django

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

Buenas a todos, 
Tengo el siguiente error al trabajar con formularios dinámicos en Django con jquery, 
El error es: ***['Los datos de ManagementForm faltan o han sido manipulados']***
ya revise la documentación que encontré e hice varios cambios a mi código pero no puedo levantar el error.
el código que tengo es el siguiente:
models.py

```
class Bloque (models.Model):
condominio_blo = models.ForeignKey(Condominio, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
nombre_blo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
#presidente = models.ForeignKey(Persona)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    #return reverse ('listar-pais', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
    return reverse ('listar-bloque')

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.condominio_blo, self.nombre_blo)

class Vivienda (models.Model):
condominio_viv = models.ForeignKey(Condominio, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
bloque_viv = models.ForeignKey(Bloque, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
manzano_viv = models.CharField(max_length=3)
calle_viv = models.CharField(max_length=15)
num_vivienda = models.CharField(max_length=5)
num_habitaciones = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
num_baños = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
sup_total = models.FloatField(default=100.00)
sup_construida = models.FloatField(default=100)
pago_expensas = models.FloatField(default=260.00)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.condominio_viv, self.bloque_viv, self.manzano_viv, \
        self.calle_viv, self.num_vivienda)
```

forms.py

```
class ViviendaForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Vivienda

    fields = [
        'manzano_viv',
        'calle_viv',
        'num_vivienda',
        'num_habitaciones',
        'num_baños',
        'sup_total',
        'sup_construida',
        'pago_expensas',
    ]

    labels = {
        'manzano_viv':'Manzano',
        'calle_viv':'Calle',
        'num_vivienda':'Número / Lote',
        'num_habitaciones':'# Habit.',
        'num_baños':'# Baños',
        'sup_total':'Sup. Total Const',
        'sup_construida':'Sup. Const.',
        'pago_expensas':'Expensas',
    }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ViviendaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in iter(self.fields):
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'size': '12'})


ViviendaFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Bloque, Vivienda, form = ViviendaForm, extra = 1)
```

views.py

```
class CrearBloqueVivienda(CreateView):
"""docstring for CrearBloqueViviennda"""
model = Bloque
form_class = BloqueForm
succes_url = reverse_lazy('listar-bloque')  

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CrearBloqueVivienda, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context ['vivienda_formset'] = ViviendaFormSet(self.request.POST)
    else:
        context ['vivienda_formset'] = ViviendaFormSet()
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    formset = context ['vivienda_formset']
    if formset.is_valid():
        bloque = form.save(commit = False)
        for casa_form in form.forms:
            casa = casa_form.save(commit = False)
            casa.bloque_viv = bloque
            casa.condominio_viv = bloque.condominio_blo
            casa.save()
        bloque.save()
        return redirect (sel.succes_url)
    else:
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

class ModificarBloqueVivienda(UpdateView):
"""docstring for ModificarBloqueVivienda"""
model = Bloque
succes_url = reverse_lazy('listar-bloque')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ModificarBloqueVivienda, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.POST:
        context ['vivienda_formset'] = ViviendaFormSet(self.request.POST, instance= self.object)
        context ['vivienda_formset'].full_clean()
    else:
        context['vivienda_formset'] = ViviendaFormSet(instance = self.object)
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    formset = context['vivienda_formset']
    if formset.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save()
        formset.instance = self.object
        formset.save()
        return redirect(self.succes_url)
    else:
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Y finalmente bloque_form.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        {% if object %}
            <form role="form" action="{% url 'modificar-bloque' object.pk %}" method="post">
        {% else %}
            <form role="form" action="{% url 'nuevo-bloque' %}" method="post">
        {% endif %}
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
            <h3>Modificar Bloques</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ vivienda_formset.managment_form }}
                    <table class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-centered col-md-2"># DE VIV.</th>
                                    <th class="text-centered col-md-2">MANZANO/PISO</th>
                                    <th class="text-centered col-md-2">CALLE/PASILLO</th>
                                    <th class="text-centered col-md-2"># HABITA.</th>
                                    <th class="text-centered col-md-2">#  BAÑOS.</th>
                                    <th class="text-centered col-md-2">SUP. TERRENO</th>
                                    <th class="text-centered col-md-2">SUP. CONSTRU.</th>
                                    <th class="text-centered col-md-2">EXPENSAS</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for viviendas in vivienda_formset %}
                                    {{ viviendas.id }}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="form col-md-2">{{ viviendas.num_vivienda }}</td>
                                        <td class="form-control col-md-2">{{ viviendas.manzano_viv }}</td>
                                        <td class="form-control col-md-2">{{ viviendas.calle_viv }}</td>
                                        <td class="form-control col-md-2">{{ viviendas.num_habitaciones }}</td>
                                        <td class="form-control col-md-2">{{ viviendas.num_baños }}</td>
                                        <td class="form-control col-md-2">{{ viviendas.sup_total }}</td>
                                        <td class="form-control col-md-2">{{ viviendas.sup_construida }}</td>
                                        <td class="form-control col-md-2">{{ viviendas.pago_expensas }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </table>

                    <button id="add-item" type="button class btn-info btn-xs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                    <button id="remove-item" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Guardar">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return cerrar_modal()">Cancelar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

mi javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-item").on("click", addItem);
    $("#remove-item").on("click", removeItem);
});

function addItem() {

    form_count++;

    var form = '{{formset.empty_form|escapejs}}'.replace(/__prefix__/g, form_count);

    $('#forms').append(form)

    $('#id_vivienda_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(form_count);
}

function otroaddItem() {
    var newElement = $(".table tr:last").clone(true);
    var total = $("#id_vivienda_set-TOTAL_FORMS").val();
    newElement.find(":input").each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("name").replace("-" + (total-1) + "-", "-" + total + "-");
        var id = "id_" + name;
        $(this).attr({"name": name, "id": id}).val("");
    });
    total++;
    $("#id_vivienda_set-TOTAL_FORMS").val(total);
    $(".table tr:last").after(newElement);
    if (total > 1) {
        $("#remove-item").show();
    }
}

function removeItem() {
    var lastElement = $(".table tr:last");
    var total = $("#id_vivienda_set-TOTAL_FORMS").val();
    $(lastElement).remove();
    total--;
    $("#id_vivienda_set-TOTAL_FORMS").val(total);
    if (total < 2) {
        $("#remove-item").hide();
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que me vuelvo loco buscando cual es el error.

PD: en el script, probé tanto con la función additem como con otroadditem y el error es el mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa tu sintaxis:

```
succes_url = reverse_lazy('listar-bloque')
```

Es así : con doble 's'

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('listar-bloque')
```